# No such property: getFlatConfig when trying to access configuration

Tags: grails

So have set up a couple of values in the groovy.config file which I want for my application.

Set them as follows:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        reslist = ['1400x1200','1200x1024','1024x800','800x600']
        resdef = '1024x800'
        mapregs = ['World', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'South America','Central America', 'Pacific','Africa']
        mapdef = 'World'
```

Then I try to access them in a controller

```
if ( params.mapreq == null) {
    mapreq = grailsApplication.config.grails.mapdef
} else {
    mapreq = params.mapreq
}
```

It seems to work (kind a) I get something back, but looks like an object pointer in the format
groovy.util.ConfigObject@3764a904

Tried changing it to getFlatConfig

```
if ( params.mapreq == null) {
    mapreq = grailsApplication.getFlatConfig.grails.mapdef
} else {
    mapreq = params.mapreq
}
```

At which point I get a "No such property: getFlatConfig when trying to access configuration" instead

So any suggestions?
Also, would the same solution work for getting the lists (like the mapregs one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grailsApplication.config.grails.mapdef` should be `grailsApplication.config.mapdef` since `mapdef` is at the top level of the config (within that environment block). Since there's nothing stored under `grails.mapdef`, the value will be a new `ConfigObject`. That's why `config.a.b.c.d=1` works - each time you access a new level that doesn't exist, Groovy automatically creates a new `ConfigObject` to hold the value being set, but if you're getting and not setting, you end up with just the empty instance.

The 2nd one doesn't work because `getFlatConfig` should be `getFlatConfig()` or `flatConfig`. But you can't use the `ConfigObject`-style dots with the flat config because it's flattened. If `mapdef` was actually under `grails` you'd access it as `grailsApplication.flatConfig.'grails.mapdef'` or `grailsApplication.flatConfig['grails.mapdef']`. But like the other one it's not, so you'd use `grailsApplication.flatConfig.mapdef`.